# List Sorting numbers in Descending Order

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have a List that is not sorting at all. I used the .Sort and is not working. I want the numbers to sort in Descending order. 9,6,4,3,2

```
 List<string> tem = new List<string>();
 using (SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(connStr))
 {
       cs.Open();

       for (int x = 0; x < length; x++)
       {
           SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("spTicketIssuance_GetTransactions", cs);
                select.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransDesc", TransType[x]);

            SqlDataReader dr = select.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                tem.Add(dr["TransTime"].ToString()); //Adds all Transaction in the multiline textbox and adds them to List  TransList
            }
            dr.Close();
       }
            tem.Sort(); //NOT SORTING
            cs.Close();
        }
```

Comment: what is the result when you call `Sort`?

Comment: Sort wont work correctly unless you make your List<int> or override your sort to cast as int.

Comment: If they're numbers, why convert to string?

Comment: I have sample data for example, 12, 2 ,7 and it stills displays the same output.

Comment: You tell us what it's not doing. It'd be easier to help you if you explained what it is doing (nothing? sorting in some other order?) Additionally, if your data type is datetime or int or etc, you're making your own life harder by convering to string.

Comment: @ReacherGilt is not sorting in descending order.

Comment: @Apollo: strings don't sort like integers.  12 is < 2 in strings just as apple is less than bat.

Comment: Or modify your stored proc to sort in the expected order. Or write a new stored proc that provides the expected behavior.

Comment: Why are you sorting client-side anyway?  Just add an `ORDER BY TransTime DESC` to your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you're sorting numbers, but your list contains strings.  Sorting numerical values in strings will lead to all sorts of weird results if the numbers have differing numbers of digits.

This is exactly the problem with the sample you gave in your comment.  The string sort compares the first character (digit) and sees that 1 < 2, so it sorts 12 before 2.  If you started with `"2", "12", "7"`, you'd see it produce the same result - `"12", "2", "7"`.

If you're storing numeric values, use a numeric type for your list.

Also, `Sort()` will always sort in ascending order.  If you want it to produce a descending result you'd either need to `Reverse()` the result, or, as other answers have said, use `OrderByDescending(x => x)` instead of `Sort()`.  The latter option would be more efficient.

**Update**

I take it from your comment on @Steve's answer that the data type in the database is a character type as well?

For your text box you can do something like:

```
string[] lines = text.Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
List<int> trans = lines.Select(line => Int32.Parse(line)).ToList();
```

The second line will blow up if the entries aren't purely numerical, though.  A safer way would be something like this:

```
IEnumerable<int?> values = lines.Select(line => 
{
    int value; 
    return Int32.TryParse(line, out value) ? (int?)value : null;
})
List<int> trans = values.Where(v => v.HasValue).Select(v => v.Value).ToList();
```

This will discard any lines that can't be converted to an `int`.

Once you've got your data in numeric format, then store it in the database that way, and the rest of your processing (sorting, etc) becomes a lot easier.

**Update 2**

Like I said in my comment, the `OrderByDescending()` method doesn't change the list it's applied to, but essentially provides a different enumeration order over that list.  If you need the results in a list just add `ToList()` to do that.  So:

```
List<int> sortedTrans = transInt.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList();
```

Comment: I get error. I have it like this, text.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Comment: ok I got it working now. How do I sort now by Descending? is doing it now by Ascending.

Comment: @Apollo - you need to use `.OrderByDescending(x => x)`.  This won't sort the list in place, but will give you a new `IEnumerable<int>` with the elements in the order you want.

Comment: I already have in the List<int> all numbers. My question is how do I sort it descending. The transInt.OrderByDescending(x=>x); is not working

Answer (score 2):

You could try with

```
var ordered = tem.OrderByDescending(x => x);
```

However, given the fact that you add numbers as strings, you can't get a correct order if your numbers are two digits or more.

For example

```
List<string> tem = new List<string>() {"11", "5", "4"};
var ordered = tem.OrderByDescending(x => x);
foreach(string s in ordered)
     Console.WriteLine(s);
```

will give you "5", "4", "11" because the first character "5" is greater that the first character "1" in the "11" string.
You could add the string with a format specifier that adds the character for zero like this

```
tem.Add(string.Format("{0:D3}", dr["TransTime"]));
```

and have your output correctly sorted (unless you have numbers of 4 digits and more)

EDIT: Example using a List(Of Integer) instead of a List(Of String) and put the result in a textbox

```
List<int> tem = new List<int>();
using (SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    .....
    tem.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dr["TransTime"])); 
}

var ordered = tem.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
ordered.ForEach(x => sb.AppendLine(x.ToString()));
textBox.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Actaully as he's looking for descending order you need OrderByDescending

Comment: I get this Erro No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 argument

Comment: Fixed with a string.Format, but I have to ask, why do you want to get a List of strings when your input is clearly a number? (See the answer from @AndrewCooper)

Comment: @Apollo - But why are you converting to string at all?

Comment: I have a multiline textbox and they are stored in an array.  string[] trans = text.Split(new char[] { '\n' }) I guess the easier way will be how do I store this into a List<int>?

Comment: Added the example using a List(Of Integer)

Answer (score 1):

use the

list.OrderByDescending

Would help

Comment: Steve posted this with a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = new List<string> { "abc", "xyz" };
var srotedDesc = names.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList();
```